# Accessing http upload data before upload completion

Tags: python, http, upload, cgi

Is there any way to access a file being uploaded over http using a CGI script *before* the upload finishes? For example, say a 10 megabyte file is being uploaded, and is exactly 10% done, meaning the server has 1 megabyte of data. Is it possible to read that 1 megabyte of data without waiting for the upload to finish?

My understanding of http uploads is that the server won't call the CGI script handling the upload until all of the data is received, but I'm hoping there's some way around that. I'm using python to handle CGI requests if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGI is the specification of communication between the web server and the external application.  It does not allow for this.

In fact, most web servers won't do anything with an upload until it finishes, but there's no reason you couldn't write/change one (or MAYBE find one, but I don't know which it would be) to allow access, but you're still not going to do it via a CGI.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. I'll probably have to write my own server to handle the HTTP protocol in a non-standard way, which is a _lot_ of work. Oh, well. Thanks anyway.